# Is each connection backed by one Thread in Database Connection Pooling?

Tags: java, multithreading, database-connection, connection-pooling

In Database connection Pooling,

- does each connection correspond to 1 thread in the database ?
- Would it really matter ? I mean, there could be a threadPool
  executor, that execute whatever a connection Object has to execute ?

I wonder how it works, because that would help in understanding how this things is actually tuned.

My understanding so far is **"one connection - one thread"**. Otherwise why most database would be blocking ?

Comment: What dbms are you using?  What java driver/connector are you using?

Comment: @kdbanman I think having an approach that consist in understanding the general picture of what you are doing is as important as the specific code that you might implement. A little bit of abstraction is not a bad thing.

Comment: However to answer your question, i am working with a TripleStore called Stardog. The database client, propose to set up your pool size. The vendor gives some recommendation. But in general, i think understanding how to tune this things, requires some deeper understanding about thread and the  functioning of database.

Comment: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing

Comment: You speak of an "it" without naming the beast. It depends on the pool. In the one created by my server, each pooled connection equates to one thread in the database. That is the characteristic of my "it". That is no guarantee that all "its" work like that.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the input @Gimby

Answer (score 4):

Connection pooling is what you have on client side (i.e. in Java).

The connection pool is just that - a pool of open connections to the database. These are not bound to threads, any number of threads can request connection from the pool at any given time - the pool will grant the request if a connection is available, and if not, it will either create a new one, block or deny the request (depends on implementation). The main idea here is to have *less connections than threads*, another purpose is to *keep those connections open* if there's many short DB operations (the creation of DB connection is an expensive operation).

On the server side, this depends on the DB implementation. I would expect most DB servers to use one thread per connection - someone has to listen on the open socket after all. For many DB engines this can be much more complex though, e.g. there may be one module listening on the socket, and in turn sending the queries to another module that may have different number of threads running.

Comment: I think your answer help me. It was nice to remind me of the client side of things. However i think that whatever you do on the client side is impacted by what you do on the server side.

Comment: I read a very nice blog post on the matter. https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing,  I think it is well grounded. However, they don't seem to make distinction between your threadPool and what is happening on the database? Or maybe i am wrong and the person is only thinking about the number of thread on the client side. Nevertheless it seems that the assumption is one thread per connection (in the client side)

Comment: I think saying "The main idea here is to have less connections than threads" is too simplistic. The blog that i shared, says a bit more about that. But the reasoning, is more, take care of the architecture of your machine and have a number of connection proportional to it. In this case, he means, have a number of thread per connection, that mirror the number of core you have, modulo some formula to take into account, disc access and network and etc...

Comment: It is that last part that puzzle me, because the Disk access would be related to where the database is actually situated, it would be more of a server issue that a client issue as u seem to be careful to distinguish.